# In SQL, is there a way to do a UNION with a comparison of a field between the two tables?

Tags: mysql, sql

In SQL, is there a way to do union between two tables such that the results are filtered by a common condition between the two tables?

Basically I want to do this...

```
SELECT City, Country FROM Customers
UNION ALL
SELECT City, Country FROM Suppliers
WHERE Customers.Country = Suppliers.Country
```

Including some sample data...

```
Customers
City       Country
Alb        USA
Alb        UK
NY         Russia

Suppliers
City       Country
LA         USA
DesMoines  UK
NY         USA
```

And I would want to return the record from Customer that has a City designation of Alb - plus the records from Supplier that have the same Country designation that is the same as the record from Customer that has a City designation of Alb.

Now that I've looked at it for a bit - I see that I need to do a nested SQL statement...

```
Select * from Supplier
Where Country =
    (Select Country from Customer Where City = 'Alb')
```

Sorry for the confusion everyone - I just needed to think about it for a minute.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  What you want to do is unclear.

Comment: It looks like you'd probably be more interested in a JOIN than a UNION; but as Gordan stated, it's a bit unclear as initially presented.

Comment: "In SQL, is there a way to do union between two tables such that the results are filtered by a common condition between the two tables?" had a feeling you are looking for SQL [INTERSECT](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-intersect/)? "The INTERSECT operator compares the result of two queries and returns the distinct rows that are output by both left and right queries."  The link simulate INTERSECT because it's not supported in MySQL.

Comment: Thanks.  Is there a way to to a comparison between the two tables using INTERSECT?

Comment: Hello Tim, in order to get an accurate answer from the community, would you please provide sample data and expected results ? This will help people figuring out what you exactly are after.

Comment: what version of mysql are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want the result set to be a list

- of all the customers that are located in a country that a supplier also located in.
- and of all the suppliers that are located in a country that a customer is also located in.

You could use a [Common Table Expression](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html#common-table-expressions-syntax) (CTE), which basically creates an temporary table view of data for a given query. It maybe only be available in the current version of MySql (version 8.0).

I setup your example data on <kbd>[DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/spqXwQeNK418zEdgsxEeP1/0)</kbd> and got the results you described with this query using a CTE.

```
WITH cteCommonCountries AS 
(
    SELECT Customers.Country 
    FROM Customers 
    JOIN Suppliers 
    WHERE Customers.Country = Suppliers.Country
)
SELECT City, Country from Customers where Country IN (SELECT Country from cteCommonCountries)
UNION
SELECT City, Country from Suppliers where Country IN (SELECT Country from cteCommonCountries);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can apply the filter to each table:

```
SELECT City, Country FROM Customers
WHERE Country IN (SELECT Country FROM Suppliers)
UNION ALL
SELECT City, Country FROM Suppliers
WHERE Country IN (SELECT Country FROM Customers)
```

You can use `UNION` instead of `UNION ALL` if you get duplicates.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions; I do appreciate them.

The reason I don't think a JOIN is going to work in this case is that I need to have separate records returned from both tables rather than the fields for both tables returned within the same record.

Comment: I'm not sure that a JOIN would do better in this case.